# Interpolating gaps in raster layer based on another layer

Tags: r, matrix, raster

I have raster layer with data gaps (`r1`), I want to fill the gaps in it using n number of neighboring cells, provided that these cells have a common value in `r2`. I hope the following example can give the idea.

```
library(raster)
r1 <- raster(ncol=4, nrow=4)
r1[] <- c(1:6,NA,4:9,NA,1,2)

r2 <- raster(ncol=4, nrow=4)
r2[] <- c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,3,3,4,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You provide two data sets, but not an example. That is, you do not explain what you would like the result to be. None of the neighboring cells of the `NA` cells in `r1` have the same value as these cells in `r2` (only the very first cell of `r1` and `r2` have the same value, so it seems that there is no solution.)

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
s <- overlay(r1, r2, fun=function(x,y){ y <- x == y; y[!y] <- NA; y })
x <- focal(s, w=matrix(1,5,5), fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, pad=T)
r <- cover(r1, x)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, perhaps I should say it this way: `r2` has `4` categories, I want to fill the gaps in `r1` using all the cells with the same category in `r2`. In this case the first NA has value of 2 in `r2`, so all of the neighbor cells with value of `2` in `r2` should be used to fill the gap.